# websocket basic authentication in cordova vs. Chrome

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I have a Cordova app and when I use websocket to do basic authentication in Chrome it works:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://user:password@192.168.1.10');
```

When I run in Android emulator, I always get a 401 error.

```
Unexpected response code: 401
```

If I disable authentication in server side, then both Android emulator and Chrome work, so my guess is that something in Cordova is making it impossible for authentication to work. Any clues on what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you checking for errors or other clues in your server-side logs?

Comment: Server is fine. I'm 90% positive it is a Cordova related issue. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: This is not something I've done with Cordova; just asking about other possibilities that you hadn't mentioned in your question. Which WebSocket plugin are you using, and are you getting any additional details in your `logcat` output?